# More elegant approach to append text to a file only if the String doesn't exist?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to append NoDisplay=true to a .desktop file, but only if the entry doesn't exist. I do this the following way:

```
grep -q 'NoDisplay=true' '/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop' || bash -c 'echo "NoDisplay=true" >> /usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop'
```

I was wondering if there is a shorther oneliner for the same operation?

I use this command in a bash script and had to use command "bash -c".

Comment: I answered this before [on the vi/Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have GNU `sed`, it's fairly simple:

```
sed -zi '/NoDisplay=true/!s/$/\nNoDisplay=true/' file
```

Option `-z` treats the whole line at once in the pattern space (not recommended for huge files). If the setting is not (`!`) found, append it at the end with an embedded newline. Note: `-i`, `-z` and `\n` in the replacement string are not standard, so this is not portable.

Comment: I don't know why, but it adds `NoDisplay=true` for every line when used with `-i` on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. It is OK with out the `-i` though.

Comment: My mistake: You can't combine options `-i` and `-z` as `-iz`, because this will treat `z` as a suffix for the backup file for inplace editing. `-i -z` or `-zi` should work. Thank you for the input, @ctrl-alt-delor!

Comment: Ah yes obvious, when you point it out.

Comment: Thanks alot, I went with this. Altough many good answers here this line satisfied my needs and my OCD :)

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit shorter.

```
grep -q 'NoDisplay=true' '/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop' || echo "NoDisplay=true" >> /usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop
```

There is also a tool designed for this Augeas (`augtool`). I have not used it with `.desktop` file. So can not help with how to use it.

Comment: You should add the `-F` and `-x` flags to that `grep` command, for fixed text matching and whole line matching respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, based off [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/976712):

```
sed -i "/^NoDisplay=true\$/h;\${x;/^\$/{s//NoDisplay=true/;H};x}" '/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop'
```

Broken down without escaping `$`s:

```
# Store the line in the hold space if found
/^NoDisplay=true$/h

# At the end of the file
${
    # Switch to the hold space
    x
    # If it's empty
    /^$/{
        # Replace the line
        s//NoDisplay=true/
        # Store it in the hold space
        H
    }
    # Switch to the hold space
    x
}
```

It's possible to do in `awk`, but since there's no [inplace editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) before GNU 4.1.0, you'd essentially be doing the same thing as `grep`+`echo`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only possibly inelegant things in your approach are the use of a `bash -c`, which is not required, and the redundancy of the literal strings you used for the pattern and the filename, which are in fact what make your one-liner long, and which you could instead put in variables (perhaps short-named) to be used like in:

```bash
p='NoDisplay=true' f='/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop'; grep -q "${p}" "${f}" || echo "${p}" >>"${f}"
```

You could make this a bit more compact by playing with redirections, just to avoid specifying the filename twice, hence avoiding one variable, like in:

```bash
p='NoDisplay=true'; (grep -q "${p}" || echo "${p}" >&0) <>/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop
```

But whether that is actually elegant is probably a matter of preference.

Anyways, the pattern still needs to be specified twice, although through variables. I can't imagine ways where you could avoid that.

Yet another variant with `sed`, which would save only a few keystrokes more, could be:

```bash
p='NoDisplay=true'; sed -n "/${p}/q;\$a${p}" <>/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop >&0
```

Requires GNU `sed` (typically present on Linux) due to the `a` command immediately followed by the text to be appended (the pattern's variable in our case).

The same for POSIX `sed` would be:

```bash
p='NoDisplay=true'; sed -n "/${p}/q;\$a\\
${p}
" <>/usr/share/applications/yelp.desktop >&0
```